# "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)" in the fpr, tpr calculation on sklearn ROC example

Tags: python, scikit-learn, roc

My code to plot the ROC curve,

'''

```
true = y_true
pred = preds[:,0]
fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()
for i in range(2):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(true, pred)
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])

print(roc_auc_score(test, pred))
plt.figure()
plt.plot(fpr[1], tpr[1])
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic')
plt.show()
```

'''

However, I receive the error, "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)" in the for loop for fpr, tpr calcuation. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks for your time.

Comment: `fpr[i], tpr[i] = roc_curve(true, pred)` instead of `fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(true, pred)`

Comment: @RobinFrcd Thanks, I thought the last variable was thresholds. However, it cleared it, but I am receiving an empty graph as the plot. my tpr values are nan, "{0: tensor([nan, nan, nan]), 1: tensor([nan, nan, nan])}". Any ideas?

Comment: Take a deeper look at your true and pred tensors, they may be faulty (ie: full of nan)

Comment: Looks clean, no NaN values on both positive and negative class

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: I'm not sure if sklearn will be able to handle tensors; you may need to convert to numpy first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from sklearn import metrics 
true = y_true
pred = preds[:,0]
fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()
for i in range(2):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = metrics.roc_curve(true, pred)
    roc_auc[i] = metrics.auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])

print(roc_auc_score(test, pred))
plt.figure()
plt.plot(fpr[1], tpr[1])
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic')
plt.show()
```